# Weird padding issues loading a struct from an array buffer (coming from a raw socket). How to fix?

Tags: c, sockets

I have defined the following structs for an ARP header:

```
typedef uint8_t MacAddress[6];

typedef struct
{
    MacAddress Destination;
    MacAddress Source;
    uint16_t Type;
} EthernetHeader;

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t    HardwareType;
    uint16_t    ProtocolType;

    uint8_t     HardwareAddressLength;
    uint8_t     ProtocolAddressLength;
    uint16_t    Operation;

    MacAddress  SenderHardwareAddress;
    uint32_t    SenderProtocolAddress;
    MacAddress  TargetHardwareAddress;
    uint32_t    TargetProtocolAddress;
} ArpHeader;
```

My problem is that `SenderProtocolAddress` is getting padded 2 bytes to the right, so its actually reading half of itself and part of `TargetHardwareAddress`. The same thing happens again with the targets, except `TargetProtocolAddress` is padded 4 bits to the right this time (all zeroes because it went beyond the actual content of the buffer.

I have no idea why this is happening, as the Ethernet struct reads just fine with the MacAddress type I made just fine, and every piece of data up until the last 4 reads exactly as intended. I'm at a loss, what is wrong here?

Comment: That's because `SenderProtocolAddress` is not aligned to a 32-bit address. Add a 2-byte padding before it (and also before `TargetProtocolAddress`).

Comment: if I add 2 bytes before `SenderProtocolAddress` it will not read the actual ip address. What's happening is [6 byte MAC][2 bytes not being read][4 byte ip address]. I need to make it read the 2 bytes its currently skipping over for some reason.

Comment: Oh, right, the compiler does it automatically, and that's why you get these wrong values. Then use `#pragma pack(push,1)` before the declaration and `#pragma pack(pop)` after the declaration.

Comment: You mean "padded 4 *bytes* to the right?" As Barak says, the structure needs to be packed if you are reading the whole thing with a single operation.

Comment: If you'r using gcc, add `__attribute__((packed))` to the definition of the struct to inform the compiler not to pad. (EDIT: Note that on some architectures, it is _not_ ok to access certain types/sizes on unaligned addresses.)

Comment: @Jite that worked perfectly. Thanks! Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @elite5472 Said and done. Glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'r using gcc, add `__attribute__((packed))` to the definition of the struct to inform the compiler not to pad.

Note that on some architectures, it is not ok to access certain types/sizes on unaligned addresses (some ARMv6 implementations for instance).

As Frank says, it's possible to create a big buffer and use offsets to get rid of these type of problems. On the other hand you will have to keep track of offset sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use compiler specific alignment attributes/pragmas, but I think it's best not to use structs in this way unless you really need the performance.

Just write functions to marshall between the struct and a buffer. You won't have to worry about the platform endianness this way either.